# Numeral.JS zeroFormat includes $ and % symbol at end result

Tags: numeral.js

Why does zero formatting include $ and % symbols in the formatted result?
`numeral.js` version is `1.5.3`

```
var number = numeral(0);

numeral.zeroFormat('N/A');

var zero = number.format('0.0%')
// 'N/A%'

var zero = number.format('$0.0')
// '$N/A'

// What I expect is 'N/A'
```

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Problem duplication - https://jsfiddle.net/wbuu53qr/

Answer (score 1):

Quickly found the solution. This problem happens in the older version.
Just have to move to the latest version:

```
var number = numeral(0);

numeral.zeroFormat('N/A');

var zero = number.format('0.0%')
// 'N/A'
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4jz4vp5h/